# Where is IE 11 History located on the FS?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

What is the location on the filesystem for the IE 11 history storage?

- [IE 10 stores](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) in C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\
- IE 5-9 stores in in a [few locations](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_History_File_Format#File_Locations)

IE 11 doesn't appear to be using the locations for IE 10 or any earlier version.  The C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\ is empty, and the IE 5-9 locations do not show any history files on my system even though the browser has entries in the history when you look at it through the user interface.

Internet Explorer is such a noisy application that I am not finding anything obvious when use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch all filesystem access from iexplore.exe.

The real problem is that I am trying to figure out why IE 11 history seems to get lost on systems that are setup for roaming profiles.

Answer (score 4):

This is in-progress spelunking. It looks like the only place the history is being recorded is in this file:

AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Low\SuggestedSites.dat

Comment: Keep in mind that I am looking for the **browsing history** not the cache/temporary internet files location.  That location doesn't appear to have the history on my test system, in fact the `C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Packages\windows_ie_ac_001` folder seems completely empty.

Comment: `LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local`

Answer (score 2):

In windows 7 Internet explorer 11 will make another file if you close internet explorer delete & then reopen IE. How ever mine is not the same as the first one. You can make this folder your self by creating a folder go to properties, customize, change icon. You will need to select "system32\SHELL32.dll" to find the icon. It is on the bottom about 80% of the way to the right. You will on find several yellow triangles with exclamation marks on them. The clock with an green arrow pointing counterclockwise select it. General tab select hidden apply changes to this folder only. You will need to make an .ini file with

[.ShellClassInfo]

ConfirmFileOp=0

CLSID={FF393560-C2A7-11CF-BFF4-444553540000}

UICLSID={7BD29E00-76C1-11CF-9DD0-00A0C9034933}

to replace the one created by changing the icon no spaces between lines. Once you apply this .ini file you will not be able to change the properties any more. So make sure you got it the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

Comment: Has ***desktop.ini*** file and ***Low*** is _empty_

Answer (score 0):

Under the  Users - (Username) - Appdata - Local - Microsoft - Windows 
There should be a History folder (Which is hidden) with a clock and green arrow.
This folder cannot be created, I believe it was installed, however the folder was missing.
By copying the folder from another user from the same location Users - (OtherUsername) - Appdata - Local - Microsoft - Windows and pasting to the Users - (Username) - Appdata - Local - Microsoft - Windows location where it was missing, Internet Explorer 11 immediately started creating a history.

Comment: Where ***path*** location of ***files*** from **History** `folder`? Maybe `*.dat files` ?