# Physical location of internet Explorer V11 history

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am searching an answer to my question but i failed to find since two weeks . I'm developing an application that recuperate history and information about browsers . I didn't find any problem while analyzing history of chrome and Firefox . But for Internet Explorer 11 , i didn't find where It stores its history .Can some one know physical path of usefull files that stores history and other information .

> I find c:/users/username/appdata/local/microsoft/windows/inetcache

It contains many files but i think it is useless files . I'm using windows 8.1 .

Comment: `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History`

Comment: [Where is IE 11 History located on the FS?](https://superuser.com/questions/678497/where-is-ie-11-history-located-on-the-fs?rq=1)

Comment: C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History , it is not usefull , it contains history of windows operations (exemple , file edited )+history browsing even the browser . I doesn't solve my problem . @Seth i show the post and it doesn't help me .

Answer (score 1):

Finally , i find usefull link [Read here](https://cyberarms.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/windows-8-forensics-internet-cache-history/)

Internet Explorer stores its history in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\ in file called WebCacheV01.dat (Extensible Storage Engine ) database .

Answer (score 0):

From past experience with looking for forensic data recovery, I have uses this site for information - http://kb.digital-detective.net/display/BF/Location+of+Internet+Explorer+11+Data. This is a great site for information purposes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link doesn't solve my problem . Some document are in XML Format and it displays useless information . Only C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History displays the history of all browser and history of windows (file edited , created ...) .So i'm searching for a file that stores history of IE and this link doesn't solve my problem .